# How can I shuffle multiple independent data list with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, random

Good afternoon!

I have multiple data set (numeric) in the same number of rows (data set per row). Those data set have equal size.
I'd like to rearrange randomly and independently the values in my different lines (=keeping the values if a same set on its original row but changing its column).
I would like to keep shuffling the different lines until the sum value of each column meet some conditions. I'm used to code simple loops in VBA, but I'm blocked with my shuffling problem.
Here is an example of datasets I'd like to shuffle:

[image: Example of Datasets]

I hope I could describe clearly what I'm trying to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the conditions for the columns to meet?
And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want the sum values to be comprised between 0 and 10. But again, this is not part of my problem since I coded many loops with this kind of conditions in the past. So far I couldn't try anything concerning the shuffling of the values since I have no idea what kind of function I should use, my experience with VBA is globally limited to If then / Do Loop / For next functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub shuffle_row(rng As Range, Optional Permutations = 2)
    Randomize
    a = rng.Rows(1) 'get values from row to array
    cnt = UBound(a, 2)
    For i = 1 To cnt * Permutations   ' permutation loop
        x = Int(Rnd() * cnt + 1)    'formula = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
        y = Int(Rnd() * cnt + 1)
        If x <> y Then ' swap values at x and y positions
            Z = a(1, x): a(1, x) = a(1, y): a(1, y) = Z
        End If
    Next
    rng.Rows(1).Value = a   'output the modified series
End Sub

Sub UsageExample()
    For i = 0 To 4
        shuffle_row Range("B1:P1").Offset(i), Permutations:=3
    Next
End Sub
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Comment: Brilliant, even though I'm not quite sure to understand every line, it seems to work perfectly. Many thanks.